# How to manually add a .txt file at page root in Gatsby JS?

Tags: google-analytics, gatsby

I want to retrieve access to a Google Analytics account. Google has advised me to create an analytics.txt file at the root of the website such that `htttp://my-site.com/analytics.txt`.

How do you manually place a `.txt` file at the root of a site using Gatsby? Gatsby compiles JS files into HTML. I've tried manually placing an analytics.txt file in the `/public` folder but that doesn't seem to have worked either.

The Gatsby documentation is not helpful on this topic.

We are deploying the site using Netlify and storing the source code on Git Lab.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you create in your root project a folder named `static`, it will compile with the same name and internal structure in the `public` folder, so you will be able to refer to those files and assets in your React components. You can check for further information in their [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/).

However, in your case, you may want to use a Gatsby plugin to place your analytics code. Here's the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-analytics/).

In the scenario you've described, your solution didn't work because the `public` folder is regenerated in each build/compilation of code so your `.txt` is deleted in each compilation.